# Why have some plural pronouns replaced singular pronouns?

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, pronouns

While today we use for example the word "you" for second person singular and plural in objective and subjective manner, there were actually words to differentiate this usages like "thou" and "thee", along with many other pronouns and irregular verbs (that can be looked up in [this table](http://dan.tobias.name/frivolity/archaic-grammar.html) for example).

How come this parts of the language, especially specifying forms basically does not exist in today's language?

Comment: Apart from `ye`, it looks like it is only the second person singular pronouns that have disappeared (`thou`, `thee`, `thy/thine`). I have a suspicion that the disappearance of the second person singular pronoun ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou#History ) from most dialects of English (but see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou#Persistence_of_second-person_singular )  *may* be connected with its adoption by the Quakers ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaker ) - however, I have not seen any direct evidence for this.

Comment: @Mark: I doubt we dumped *thou/thee/thy* because it was "contaminated" by association with Quakers, Amish, etc. More likely ***you*** had more "upmarket, formal" connotations (cf [French **tutoyer**](http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/onpeutsetutoyer.htm) and our [royal "we"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majestic_plural)). And it's not *so* long ago that *thou/thee/thy* was common in the North of England. People don't use it today because it has overtones of being "unsophisticated rustic", as much as "archaic".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The second link in my previous comment included some examples of *current* usage of "thou". My suspicion is based on timing (late 17th century for both the rise of the Society of Friends and the disappearance of 2nd person singular from Southern English), together with the persistence of "thou" in areas where Quakerism was historically strong. But as I say, I have no direct evidence (which is why this is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: @MarkBannister Actually, it's the other way around: the Quakers clung to an old distinction which had been dying in the prestige dialect for two or three generations before Fox and Nayler came along. The distinction is already inconsistent in Shakespeare.

Comment: @Mark: I don't suppose for one minute there's a *single* reason, but I think StoneyB's term "prestige dialect" probably embodies the most important factor. I was a student in France over 40 years ago, and it was noticeable even then that native French students from the bigger metropolitan areas were less likely to use "tu" ("vous" often being seen as more "formal, grown-up, forward-looking"). Plus ca change, and all that.

Comment: Actually, singular *they* is well on its way to replacing something or other.

Comment: In some places we see *you* and *y'all* ... And how about *youse*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember when I was very young, my grandpa used to use the words *thou* and *thee* and *wert* and *wast*, as well as other people in Yorkshire.

When I was at school, these words were used to express a closeness to people, and as I was growing up, they were removing all these words from the old school books, and *thou wast* became you were.  However, there were children who came from close agricultural family backgrounds, whose parents spoke in the old way, and they said things like you *wast* instead of you *were*.  Eventually, this seems to have become *you was,* and finally *you were*, as the schools drove out the old way of speaking.

I think this has also partly happened due to the breakdown of family closeness these days, and the words that had a meaning of this have started disappearing.  This also includes words such as *shall, ought, hence* (in the old imperative sense) and other words that talk of duty, and they are replaced with more relative words that lack strength.  People have just become more spiritually and socially insular these days, and the language reflects this.

Comment: I don't think 'insular' is the word you really want there.

Comment: @Mitch He’s from the Isles: he cannot help but be insular.

Comment: @Mitch: I think he used the word appropriately. Man is an island.

Comment: @tchrist, Cerb Ha ha, you guys are crazy.